# Infinispan .NET Core Client Support

Tags: asp.net-core, infinispan

Our team would like to use an Infinispan client in an ASP.NET core DOCKER environment. The last version seems to be an 8.3.0-Alpha1 version on Nuget.org, which is almost 2 years old. Are there any plans to get this into a release version and make it current?

Answer (score 0):

I've assembled two new .nupkg Hotrod clients for Fedora31 and Windows10-VS14.
They're based on the 8.3.1.Final version released on the [Infinispan web site](https://www.infinispan.org).
Packages contain native libraries, please consider to build it by yourself following the [readme](https://github.com/infinispan/dotnet-client) if you need a different build for your specific platform.
For more info, meet the Infinispan Team at [infinispan.zulipchat.com](https://infinispan.zulipchat.com/)